# perl declare and export variables from a module

Tags: perl, perl-module

I need to modify a bunch of scripts to do the equivalent of a straight C style "include" of a moderate number of variables.  After the "use" to pull these in it should act exactly as if a line like this had been included:

```
my $os_name = "Windows"; #declares the variable AND sets its value
```

So that they may be used in the "calling" script. There is a little bit of logic in the module that conditionally sets the values of these variables. The scripts all have "use strict".   A typical "caller" has:

```
use strict;
use File::Basename;
use lib dirname (__FILE__);
use os_specific;
print "DEBUG os_name $os_name\n";
```

and the module (os_specific.pm) has:

```
package os_specific;
use warnings;
use strict;
use Exporter;
our @EXPORT = qw($os_name);
our $os_name="Windows";
1
```

But it doesn't work, there are compile stage warnings like:

```
Global symbol "$os_name" requires explicit package name at caller.pl.
```

So the declaration of the variable in the module is not effective at the caller's scope.

Can this be done, or must each of these variables also be declared in caller.pl?  (All responses please employ "use strict" - without that it can be done using a "require".  That doesn't work with "use strict" though because it throws a compile time error.)

I know the variables from the module can be used as "$os_specific::os_name", the question is how to set this up so that they can be used as just "$os_name".

Thanks.

Comment: `os_specific` and `OS_SPECIFIC` are not the same case.

Comment: ... unless you're on Windows.

Comment: Perl already has [$^O](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$^O): see `perl -E "say $^O"`

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you aren't inheriting any functionality from `Exporter` because you haven't set the `@ISA` package variable.

Your module should look like this, after fixing the package name (packages should use upper and lower case letters only, by convention) and should be in the file `OSSpecific.pm`

```
package OSSpecific;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter;
our @ISA    = qw/ Exporter /;
our @EXPORT = qw/ $os_name /;

our $os_name = "Windows";

1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need an explicit `import` method in your package, as demonstrated in [`Exporter`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html).

You also need to fix the casing of your package name, the filename, and your use statement so they all match.

`OS_Specific.pm`:

```
package OS_Specific;
use warnings;
use strict;
use Exporter qw(import);
```

And the other file:

```
use OS_Specific;
```

Check out [`perlstyle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html) for useful guidelines on picking package names:

> Perl informally reserves lowercase module names for "pragma" modules like [`integer`](http://perldoc.perl.org/integer.html) and [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html). Other modules should begin with a capital letter and use mixed case, but probably without underscores due to limitations in primitive file systems' representations of module names as files that must fit into a few sparse bytes.

Comment: When I added the "qw(import)" after "use Exporter" the caller still cannot access "$os_name", only "$os_specific::os_name".  The first form elicits an '"$os_name" requires explicit package name' compile time error.

Comment: Your Package name, your file name, and your the use statement, all need to use the same casing.

Comment: Is it not the case that only the pm file name and the use statements must match?  The package name in this case only defines the prefix for $os_specific::os_name.

Comment: Actually, on windows you can get away with only the `use` and `package` matching, and the file being of different casing.  But don't do that!  Make things match.

Comment: Please allow me to reiterate.  Using exporter there is no problem setting $os_name in the module and using it as "$os_specific:os_name" in a perl script that has done "use OS_Specific".  However, neither "use Exporter qw(import);" nor "use Exporter;
our @ISA    = qw/ Exporter /;
" eliminates the requirement for the "os_specific::" prefix at each use.  Is there not some way to make exporter place the name into the caller's name space?

Comment: @user3681409 You need to follow **ALL** of the instructions in my post.  You also need to fix the casing of the package name: `package OS_Specific;`.  If you had done that, then using `"$os_specific:os_name"` would not work.  Casing matters.